# What does standardization among texts mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> Prior to Gutenberg's invention, which involved the use of moveable type, books were expensive and relatively scarce, as each text was painstakingly copied by hand over a period of weeks or months.  As a result, the transmission and preservation of knowledge relied heavily upon oral, or spoken, communication and memorization, particularly among the vast majority of people who could not read or write.  For those with access to manuscript books, the lack of **standardization among texts** and the time-consuming process of duplication limited the accuracy and speed.  ("The Birth of Print Culture: The Invention of the Printing Press in Western Europe." Science and Its Times, edited by Neil Schlager and Josh Lauer, vol. 3, Gale, 2001. Student Resources in Context)

What on earth does the phrase "standardization among texts" mean?  Does it refer to double space, single space, etc OR literally space between words in a sentence?  Could you help me clarify it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think they mean spacing in particular. I think the intended meaning is quite vague and covers many aspects in which "texts" (**books**) differed between each other.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to anything before the invention of typewriters, the term **manuscript** means books that were written out by hand (from the latin manu- by hand, script - writing).

This sentence from a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuscript) may shed some light on **the lack of standardization among texts**.

> Because of the likelihood of errors being introduced each time a manuscript was copied, the filiation of different versions of the same text is a fundamental part of the study and criticism of all texts that have been transmitted in manuscript.

Lack of standardization means that errors are introduced each time a document is written out by hand. Each copy of a particular book ends up being unique.